# How to pass different DataType values in hypothesis and how to check return type and value is correct in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert, hypothesis-test, python-hypothesis

Doing sample code for Unit Test in Python with Hypothesis module.
Wrote simple `getTimeDelta` function to get time difference between two dates.

Want to write Unit Test of the `getTimeDelta` function. Used hypothesis modules to get multiple `datetime` values.

Question is that:
 1. How to I pass different data type values i.e. `time1` is str
 and `time2` is `datetime` without writing multiple functions?

2. checking only datatype of return value, not actual result is correct or not. How to do that?
3. How to check data types of items, of result tuple? `assertIsInstance`

Code:

```
import unittest
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis import strategies as st
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse as time_parse

def getTimeDelta(time1, time2):
    try:
        if isinstance(time1, str):
            time1 = time_parse(time1)
        if isinstance(time2, str):
            time2 = time_parse(time2)
        return (time1 - time2, {"message": ""})
    except Exception as err:
        return (False, {"message": "Exception {}".format(err)})

class TestTimeDeltaCalc(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestTimeDeltaCalc, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.utils = Utils()

    @given(st.datetimes(), st.datetimes())
    def test_time_delta(self, time1, time2):
        time_delta = getTimeDelta(time1, time2)
        if time_delta[0] is False:
            self.assertIsInstance(time_delta[0], bool)
        else:
            self.assertIsInstance(time_delta[0], datetime.timedelta)

        self.assertIsInstance(time_delta[1], dict)

    @given(st.text(), st.text())
    def test_time_delta(self, time1, time2):
        time_delta = getTimeDelta(time1, time2)
        if time_delta[0] is False:
            self.assertIsInstance(time_delta[0], bool)
        else:
            self.assertIsInstance(time_delta[0], datetime.timedelta)

        self.assertIsInstance(time_delta[1], dict)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Edit 01**:

We can fix #Question1 by `hypothesis.strategies.one_of(*args)`, [link](http://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.one_of)

Answer (score 1):

1. `one_of` is exactly the right approach.
2. There are many ways to test properties (see eg [this article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/property-based-testing-2/)), but the easiest here is probably a "test oracle": just compare the result to a known-good implementation!  Otherwise, you could eg. check that the timedelta is negative/0/positive if time1 is lt/eq/gt time2 - this is basically a lower-resolution oracle.
3. Your `assertIsInstance` calls look like they'd work to me.